# How NSMapTable works

Tags: ios, swift, weak-references, strong-references

I'm trying to figure out how NSMapTable works
So I'm trying in playground the following code:

```
class Person {
    var name: String


    init(name: String ) {
        self.name = name
        print("\(name) is being initialized")
    }

    deinit {
        print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
    }
}

var hobyePerson : NSMapTable? = NSMapTable<Person, NSMutableString>
(keyOptions: .weakMemory, valueOptions: .weakMemory)

var rob : Person? = Person(name: "Rob Appleseed") // print : Rob Appleseed is being initialized

hobyePerson?.setObject("golf", forKey: rob)
hobyePerson?.count // return : 1


rob = nil // print : Rob Appleseed is being deinitialized
hobyePerson?.count // return : 1 (WHY ???!!!!)
```

as written in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmaptable#relationships): "Keys and/or values are optionally held “weakly” such that entries are removed when one of the objects is reclaimed."

why even though I initialized the object so that it has a weak reference to the key-value pair when rob is deallocated, I still have an element in hobyePerson?

Comment: http://cocoamine.net/blog/2013/12/13/nsmaptable-and-zeroing-weak-references/

Answer (score 8):

`NSMapTable`'s `weak` behavior options work best when you don't care *when* keys/values are released, but rather, you do care that the keys/values aren't strongly retained and *will be released* at some point after the object of interest becomes `nil`.

Why so?

As a Foundation class, the authors of `NSMapTable` had to balance both features and performance.

Consequently, as an "optimization" for performance, they chose that weakly referenced objects that become `nil` are NOT immediately removed from the map table...! Rather, this happens "later" when it can be efficiently done -- such as when the map table internally gets resized, etc.

As @Luke also mentions in his answer, see this excellent writeup about an experiment done on `NSMapTable`'s behavior for more details:

http://cocoamine.net/blog/2013/12/13/nsmaptable-and-zeroing-weak-references/

Comment: Thank you for this lead. It is great. Along 38 years of programming in the Apple garden, most of which in Obj-C and Cocoa - I found that Apple's designers of CoreFoundation and  Foundation created a masterpiece. If you just "Forget about it" - and drive your way - your code will perform REALLY GOOD. Not just "mediocre". If you want to really excel - you may need to tweak a little, but no more. I wrote Audio/Video realtime codecs and effects...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a strange and unfortunate behavior. [This article](http://cocoamine.net/blog/2013/12/13/nsmaptable-and-zeroing-weak-references/) goes into it in some depth. Although it doesn't explore weak-to-weak specifically, the behavior described is the same. As that author notes, `hobyePerson.keyEnumerator().allObjects.count` and `hobyePerson.objectEnumerator().allObjects.count` will contain 0 as expected at the end of all this. He also points out that Apple has sort of documented this behavior in the [Mountain Lion release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-FoundationOlderNotes/#X10_8Notes).

> However, weak-to-strong NSMapTables are not currently recommended, as
>   the strong values for weak keys which get zero’d out do not get
>   cleared away (and released) until/unless the map table resizes itself.

Sorry I don't have a better explanation for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer

I think at this point NSMapTable has some sort of problem, because if I create a dictionary from hobyePerson:
    var hobyePersonDic = hobyePerson?.dictionaryRepresentation()

and add this line:
    hobyePersonDic?.isEmpty

after adding rob: 
    hobyePerson? .setObject ("golf", forKey: rob)

and after dealloc rob
rob = nil

I always get true.
I would not know whether or not the key-value pair is actually removed.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me so I implemented simple weak map like this.. Will improve it overtime but for now works:

```
import Foundation

private struct WeakValue<Value:AnyObject> {
    weak var value: Value?
}

public class CSWeakValueDictionary<Key:AnyObject, Value:AnyObject> {
    private let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    public subscript(source: Key) -> Value? {
        get {
            let value = (dictionary["\(source)"] as? WeakValue<Value>)?.value
            if value == nil { dictionary.removeObject(forKey: "\(source)") }
            return value
        }
        set { dictionary["\(source)"] = WeakValue(value: newValue) }
    }
}
```